# Countifs fails to count dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of countifss that should be counting instances of a specific word in a column where another column is between two dates (beginning and end of a week). Thanks to the input of user BruceWayne, everything compiles and runs, but the countifss fill my table with 0s. Here is the relevant part:

```
Dim thisBook As Workbook
Dim sSheet As Worksheet, rSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputRng As Range
Dim rowCount As Integer, i As Integer
Dim thisWeek As Date
Dim rSheetVal As Long

Set thisBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set rSheet = thisBook.Sheets("*** Report")
Set sSheet = thisBook.Sheets("Unique ***s")

thisWeek = Date - Weekday(Date, 2) + 1
rSheet.Range("S14").Value2 = (rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 - 49)
rSheet.Range("S15").Value2 = (rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 - 42)
rSheet.Range("S16").Value2 = (rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 - 35)
rSheet.Range("S17").Value2 = (rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 - 28)
rSheet.Range("S18").Value2 = (rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 - 21)
rSheet.Range("S19").Value2 = (rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 - 14)
rSheet.Range("S20").Value2 = (rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 - 7)
rSheet.Range("S21").Value2 = (thisWeek + 6)

For i = 14 To 21
    rSheetVal = rSheet.Cells(i, "S").Value2
    Set outputRng = rSheet.Cells(i, "T")
    With sSheet
        outputRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
            .Range("K2", "K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row), "APPROVED", _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), ">=" & (rSheetVal - 6), _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), "<=" & (rSheetVal))
    End With
    Set outputRng = rSheet.Cells(i, "U")
    With sSheet
        outputRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
            .Range("K2", "K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row), "REJECTED", _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), ">=" & (rSheetVal - 6), _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), "<=" & (rSheetVal))
    End With
    Set outputRng = rSheet.Cells(i, "V")
    With sSheet
        outputRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
            .Range("K2", "K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row), "DRAFT", _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), ">=" & (rSheetVal - 6), _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), "<=" & (rSheetVal))
    End With
    Set outputRng = rSheet.Cells(i, "W")
    With sSheet
        outputRng = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
            .Range("K2", "K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row), "ONHOLD", _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), ">=" & (rSheetVal - 6), _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), "<=" & (rSheetVal)) + _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
            .Range("K2", "K" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row), "REVIEWED", _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), ">=" & (rSheetVal - 6), _
            .Range("M2", "M" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row), "<=" & (rSheetVal))
    End With
Next i
```

Here is what the sSheet looks like:

```
    K               M
REVIEWED  ...  28 Feb 2018
APPROVED  ...  28 Feb 2018
REVIEWED  ...  27 Feb 2018
APPROVED  ...  26 Feb 2018
DRAFT     ...  26 Feb 2018
```

rSheet is the sheet with the tables and charts, sSheet is a list of tickets. The table builds itself correctly out of the end of this and the last 7 weeks, so thats fine, but after the macro runs my table is just full of 0s.

What am I missing to count these dates correctly?

Comment: This seems to me that a Pivot Table will do what you want.

Comment: Problems with dates are that Excel sees a date as a number and if your data is formatted or input as text, there can be problems with comparison and evaluating dates.  If your data is read/input from a non-Excel file, then even formatting may not change the date to a Excel date.

Comment: sSheet is defiantly a sheet in the same book as rSheet.